# Consistency of IV estimator in 2SLS

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was looking at the textbook, and in a 2SLS regression, the estimator is given by the following formula

$$\hat{\beta_{IV}} = (X'PX)^{-1}(X'PY)$$ where $P = Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'$. Given that $\mathbb{E}(ZiZ_i')$ positive definite, $\mathbb{E}(U_iZ_i) = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_iZ_i)$ full row rank, we can show that the estimator is consistent.

I am having trouble proving this statement. I tried to look for online materials but couldn't find any. Here is where I am at:
$$\hat{\beta_{IV}} = (X'PX)^{-1}(X'PY) = \beta + (X'PX)^{-1}(X'PU)$$ so we must prove the latter term goes to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}X^{\top}PX&=\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}Z_{i}^{\top}\biggr)\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_{i}Z_{i}^{\top}\biggr)^{-1}\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_{i}X_{i}^{\top}\biggr)\overset{\mathbb{P}}{\to}Q_{xz}Q_{zz}^{-1}Q_{zx},\\
\frac{1}{n}X^{\top}PU&=\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}Z_{i}^{\top}\biggr)\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_{i}Z_{i}^{\top}\biggr)^{-1}\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_{i}U_{i}\biggr)\overset{\mathbb{P}}{\to}0.
\end{align*}$$